# Telegram Bot dynamic keyboard

Tags: while-loop, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have one telegram code with `sendMessage` Method with text and keyboard.
Its for finding music.

My code is:

```
$res_media=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mv_media");
if(mysql_num_rows($res_media)!=0){
    while($resualt_media = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_media)) {
        $media[][]= $resualt_media['title'];
    }
    var_dump(
        makeHTTPRequest('sendMessage',[
            'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
            'text'=>"Chose music.",
            'reply_markup'=>json_encode(array('keyboard' => $media))
        ])
    );
}
```

and output:

[image: image description]

I want custom output
How can i add some field to keyboard with while
my database output ($media) :

```
$media=[['Button1'],['Button4']];
```

This is from database with while , now how add custom field to $media.
I want this output:

```
$media=[['Button1'],['Button4'],['MyCustomButtonForExampleBack']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in request, check out [API document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup), and following example:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: what :| what is this now? :|

Comment: @amirntm The screenshot is `reply_markup` payload, I present it by Android app

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
array_chunk($media, 4)
```

where 4 is the number of buttons in the row.